# What date to use to show when my home was established

Tags: meaning

I recently purchased a home my grandfather once lived in.  Other families lived in it between my grandfather and when I recently purchased it.  I'm have a sign made with our names on it.  When would I say it was established - from when my grandfather owned it or the date when my wife and I purchased the home and moved in??

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a personal choice based on your own preference and when *you* consider it to be established.  Please see the [help] and [tour] of the site.

Comment: You could say that you _have a connection_ to the home from the time your grandfather bought it but it would be incorrect and misleading to claim that it _had been your family home_ since that time, clearly it hasn't. Your choice will be driven, to a great extent, by your reason for having the sign made. Your use of the word "established" suggests to me that there is a commercial element to your and your grandfather's occupation of the home, is that correct?

Comment: You could look at the historical practice of putting dates and names on buildings - it's often associated with construction date, and in some places a couple would marry, build a home, and record that, but there is a lot of variation and it's not unusual to commemorate a renovation with a plaque. Your talk of "Established" doesn't seem to reflect traditional practices other than with dates a business was established - are you aiming for some ironic twist on that, maybe? Ultimately though, you can do whatever you want. And this is very off-topic for a site on English language.